# Mongoose update validation breaks the update request

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

```
  price: {
  type: Number,
  required: [true, 'A tour must have a price'],
},
priceDiscount: {
  type: Number,
  validate: function (val) {
      return val < this.price;
  }
```

The validation here tests if the discount price is less than the actual price if so it should work with no problems **(it works if I am creating a new tour on the update it doesn't)**

It just gives back a validation error even if the discount is less than the price ( "price": 997,
"priceDiscount":10)

```
"status": "FAIL",
"message": {
    "errors": {
        "priceDiscount": {
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "message": "Validator failed for path `priceDiscount` with value `10`",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Validator failed for path `priceDiscount` with value `10`",
                "type": "user defined",
                "path": "priceDiscount",
                "value": 10
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "priceDiscount",
            "value": 10
        }
    },
    "_message": "Validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Validation failed: priceDiscount: Validator failed for path `priceDiscount` with value `10`"
}
```

I already have my runValidators: true

```
exports.UpdateTour = async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const upTour = await Tour.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  });
res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    tour: `UPDATE TOUR #${req.params.id} 
               ${upTour}`,
  },
});
} catch (err) {
res.status(400).json({
  status: 'FAIL',
  message: err,
});
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that might not be optimal but it worked. I used a middleware function that checks the condition whenever the findByIdAndUpdate is triggered and it solved the problem.

[Mongoose middleware docs where I came up with this idea](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

code sample:

```
tourSchema.post(/Update$/, async function (docs, next) {
   let tour = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery());
   if (tour.price <= tour.priceDiscount) {
   //set the discount price to 0 if the price is lower
     tour.set({ priceDiscount: 0 });
     tour.save();
     next(new Error('The discount price is larger than the price'));
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Adding some code would be useful to future visitors!